FlexLayout doesn't render properly labels binding from list
In my .NET 8 MAUI project, I want to display a list of text with the properties. For example, I get this class to define the chunk of a phrase I want to display:
public class FormattedText
{
    public FontAttributes FontAttributes { get; set; } = FontAttributes.None;
    public string? Text { get; set; }
    public Color TextColor { get; set; } = Colors.Black;
}

Then, I have
public IList<FormattedText>? FormattedText { get; set; }

and I pass FormattedText in the following code
<FlexLayout
    AlignItems="Start"
    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding FormattedText}"
    Direction="Column"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label
                Padding="10"
                FontAttributes="{Binding FontAttributes}"
                Text="{Binding Text}"
                TextColor="{Binding TextColor}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>

As a result of this code, I get this output

Because this should form a proper phrase, I changed to this
<FlexLayout
    AlignItems="Start"
    BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding FormattedText}"
    Direction="Row"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label
                Padding="10"
                FontAttributes="{Binding FontAttributes}"
                Text="{Binding Text}"
                TextColor="{Binding TextColor}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>

but the output is not correct

What is it wrong? Here is the code

<FlexLayout> is not the right layout tool here because it doesn't support inline text - instead it treats children as block-rectangles which can't run-in to each other. WPF (MAUI's progenitor) has controls specifically for the layout of inline and text content - you will need to find an equivalent for MAUI.

Also, <Label> is intended for discrete rectangular blocks of text associated with other inputs - whereas you want <TextBlock> or similar here.

Here is my solution,Label exposes a FormattedText property that allows the presentation of text with multiple fonts and colors in the same view.
The FormattedText property is of type FormattedString, which comprises one or more Span instances, set via the Spans property.
For more information,please refer to Label.
   public FormattedMessage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
     
        IList<FormattedText> textList = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ".GetFormattedMessage();

       
        FormattedString formattedString = new FormattedString();
        for (int i = 0;i<textList.Count;i++) {
           
            Span sp = new Span {
            Text = textList[i].Text,
            FontAttributes = textList[i].FontAttributes
           
            };
            formattedString.Spans.Add(sp);

        }
       Label contentLabel = new Label { FormattedText = formattedString };
        contentFlex.Add(contentLabel);
     
    }


<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiTest.FormattedMessage">
    <FlexLayout  x:Name="contentFlex">
       
              
    </FlexLayout>
</ContentView>

